# How to find the middle index of Horizontal Listview(Recycler View)

Tags: android

I have the horizontal listview in which I want to find the every time middle index of a screen so that I can change its size. Basically I want to do Like fisheye effect on the middle index of Listview every time while swiping and stopping.
Kindly give me suggestion.

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    try {
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(cntx.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(apps.get(position).getAppname()));
        Log.e("TAG", "position: "+position );
           if(position%4==0) {
               holder.image.setMinimumHeight(250);
               holder.image.setMinimumWidth(250);
           }

        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PackageManager pm = cntx.getPackageManager();
                Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(apps.get(position).getAppname());
                cntx.startActivity(launchIntent);
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image: This is what I want]

Answer (score 2):

The ListView has `getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `getLastVisiblePosition()` methods. You can add these values and divide by 2. Result will be index of middle element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getItemCount() method to get the middle index of your list.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

int middleIndex=getItemCount()/2; 
}
```

This will give you the middle index value. You can write the condition on the basis of that.

Comment: getItemCount() returns the total value of a size of the array which is not my requirement, I need to get the middle of visible listview items.for example, we have 20 items of listview but visible only five rest of the item will be visible if we scroll the listview. So I need the visible items middle.I hope so you got my point